# How should I find the time from a date till today?

Tags: html

I have some problem making my website.

I want that it should display how many years, months and days have been passed from a specific date.

I haven't tried anything till yet. I am very new to website building.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+days+month+years+since+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: See if this can help you, its only days, but you can convert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript#:~:text=var%20start%3D%20%24(%22%23firstDate,round(days))%3B